# Ansible - vmware_guest - answer, or skip, banner when using 'autologon' (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, ansible, vmware

I've created an Ansible playbook for deploying and customising Windows Server VMs from a template in VMware vCenter. I'm using the 'vmware_guest' module with customisation.

During customisation the VM is domain joined. For a final step I use 'runonce' to run a powershell script that is already on the VM. 'autologon' is set to 'true' and 'autologoncount' to '1'

The problem I've encountered is after the VM is domain joined, at logon we have an "authorised user" banner that must be accepted before the logon continues.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I can 'answer' this banner as part of my playbook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vmware_guest_sendkey`.

From [`vmware_guest_sendkey` – Send USB HID codes to the Virtual Machine’s keyboard](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_sendkey_module.html)

> - name: Send list of keys to virtual machine
>
>   ```
>   vmware_guest_sendkey:
>     validate_certs: no
>     hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
>     username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
>     password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
>     datacenter: "{{ datacenter_name }}"
>     folder: "{{ folder_name }}"
>     name: "{{ vm_name }}"
>     keys_send:
>       - ENTER
>   delegate_to: localhost
>   register: keys_num_sent
>   ```

Comment: While the ansible module would work after passing the security banner, using "enter" as the send key to pass the security banner didn't work. I tested with "CTRL_ALT_DEL" after manually passing the security banner and that worked. Thanks for sharing.